# How to write code such that only one of the radio button should be selected in models with django.?

Tags: python, django, view, model, admin

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('1','Earned Leave'),('2','Casual Leave'),('3','Sick Leave'),('4','Paid Leave'))

class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)

    department = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES)

    from_date = models.DateField(help_text = 'mm/dd/yy')

    to_date = models.DateField(help_text = 'mm/dd/yy')

    reporting_manager = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = None, help_text = '0001_manager, 0002_manager')

    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)

    accepted = models.BooleanField(('accept'), default= False)

    rejected = models.BooleanField(('reject'), default = False)

    reason_reject = models.CharField(('reason for rejection'),max_length=50) // this didn't help me.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is a leave request form, where only of the two fields (`accepted, rejected`) should be selected and if the field rejected field is not selected then the `reason_reject` should not be shown in the `/admin` panel.

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from lrequests import models

class LeaveRequestForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ("name", "employee_ID", "department", "designation", "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date", "reporting_manager", "reason")
        model = models.Leave
```

The user fills the form and submits it. So, now the admin has to either accept it or reject it. The `reason_reject` field should appear to the admin only after once he selects `rejected` field. This all should happen only at the admin side.

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

@admin.register(models.Leave)
class LeaveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name"]
    #"employee_ID", "department", "designation", "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date", "reporting_manager", "reason", "accepted", "rejected", "reason_reject"
    
    list_filter = ['department','type_of_leave']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return (qs.filter(reporting_manager=request.user.username) or qs.filter(employee_ID=request.user.username))
    


 # def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
# # the logged in user can be accessed through the request object 
#     if obj and request.user.is_staff:
#         readonly_fields = [f.name for f in self.opts.fields]
#         readonly_fields.remove('accepted')
#         readonly_fields.remove('rejected')
#     return readonly_fields
#the above chunk of get_readonly_fields was written so that the admin could only either 'accept' or 'reject' the form.

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
         fields = [f.name for f in self.opts.fields]
         if obj and obj.rejected:
            fields.append('reason_reject')
         return fields
```

By running the above code I get
**`KeyError at /admin/lrequests/leave/15/change/`** and

`"Key 'id' not found in 'LeaveForm'. Choices are: accepted, department, designation, employee_ID, from_date, name, reason, reason_reject, rejected, reporting_manager, to_date, type_of_leave, user."`

Comment: are you asking about the from ?

Comment: This does not look like a *form*, but like a *model*. Furthermore the `if rejected == True`, will fail, since there a `reject` is a `BooleanField`, *not* a `bool`.

Comment: The idea is that a *model* specifies what to store in the database. In (most) databases Django supports, the number of *columns* is fixed, so whether or not the column exists does *not* exists, A form specifies how a user *enters* values. You can write some HTML/JavaScript logic to *hide* certain fields given the value of other fields, and a form can store a specific value, given other values in the form.

Comment: @amankumar I was asking about the form, after once it is submitted and the admin has to either select `accepted` or `rejected` field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, but how to tweak the code/fields in the admin panel once after the form is submitted. Where we can't access any HTML code.

Comment: But why do you think you need to do that at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Let me be clear, I've read your answer and asking on that basis. Once a leave has been requested to the user, the admin has/will have to accept or reject. If he rejects he needs to give a reason to it. But in my case for the above code in the question, the `reason_reject` has become mandatory even when admin accepts it.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question. I've updated with a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, define it as a drop down menu. That is with choices like

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (('0', 'Rejected'),('1', 'Accepted'),)
class Leave(models.Model):
     ...
     status = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = STATUS_CHOICES)
```

and then in admin.py

```
class LeaveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
     radio_fields = {"status": admin.HORIZONTAL}
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire premise is flawed. You cannot do this kind of logic in the model *definition*, because at that point there is no instance so no values to compare. And even if you could, it still wouldn't make sense because the model definition defines the database columns that the model has; you can't have different instances having different columns in the db. A model definition is for the *entire* model. You need to have `reason_reject` in the class definition.

What you might want to do is to change the form depending on the values in the model. You can do this in the admin by overriding the [`get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) method.

```
class LeaveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = [....list of fields for the form...]
        if obj and obj.rejected:
            fields.append('reason_reject')
        return fields
```

Note, you might want to think about whether you really need separate accepted/rejected fields; it would be better to have a single field for the state of the application: accepted or rejected. You can represent those either as individual radio buttons or as a dropdown.

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Accepted'),
    (0, 'Rejected'),
)
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: then how about a field appearing after selection of the `STATUS_CHOICES`?

Comment: Thanks for your support but I've got an error saying  "`'NoneType' object is not iterable`". When I have run the code with and without `def get_readonly_fields`.

Comment: Sorry, missed the return statement. Try it now.

Comment: Still the same error `TypeError at /admin/lrequests/leave/14/change/` `'NoneType' object is not iterable` the code I'm running is same as the code in my question.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. The return needs to be outside the if block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997403/how-to-hide-show-a-field-upon-selection-of-a-radio-button-in-django-admin