# How hide/show a field upon selection of a radio button in django admin?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

STATUS_CHOICES = ((1, 'Accepted'),(0, 'Rejected'),)
class Leave(models.Model):
    ----
    ----
    ----
    ----
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default = 0)
    reason_reject = models.CharField(('reason for rejection'),max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Leave

@admin.register(Leave)
class LeaveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ------
    ------
    -----

    class Media:
        js = ('/static/admin/js/admin.js')
```

-
admin.js

```
    (function($) {
    $(function() {
        var reject = document.getElementById('id_status_0')
        var accept = document.getElementById("id_status_1")
        var reason_reject = document.getElementById("id_reason_reject")
        if (accept.checked == true){
            reason_reject.style.display = "none"
        }
        else{
            reason_reject.style.display = "block"
        }
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Now I have imported the file in the admin.py, How do I trigger the jQuery function such that it works.

update-

**the function works but, I need to reload the page to make the field appear and disappear. I want some thing equivalent to `'on-click'` event in HTML. I have no idea about Javascript.**

Comment: Looks more like a frontend issue than backend. You should try executing the js content from within the browser console so that you can verify everything works as expected.

Comment: You should add a screenshot of the wanted behaviour (take 2 pictures from static views); also, a relevant excerpt of the generated HTML would be nice.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala updated!

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r the browser displays nothing.

Comment: @Jose you need to open the javascript/developer console and look for errors there!

Comment: Also, the `js` should be a *list* or *sequence* of javascript sources?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the function it self is not getting triggered there.

Comment: you say: "the function", yet I can see *4* functions. Which of these, or none of them gets triggered?! please add for example `alert('I am in global level');` or  `alert('I am change event');` around there, and find out what gets triggered and what doesn't.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's working but it's not happening dynamically, I need refresh the page every time to make the field disappear.

Comment: @Jose of course because your updated code has no event handling ... it just runs once. Why'd you change the question all the time :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you meant to say that my older question's js file had event handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="status"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '0') {
            $('#id_reason_reject').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#id_reason_reject').hide();
        }
    });
})
```